# Sticking thin counter top laminate on wall

Tags: walls, adhesive, laminate

I'm planning to stick thin high pressure laminate on painted concrete wall using contact cement. The sheets will cover the entire wall from floor to ceiling. The area total up to 9'×9'.

Standard adhesion method for contact cement will be used, that's applying thin glue coat on both surfaces, wait 15 minutes and mating them.

My concerns are these:

1. Since the sheet will be thin around 0.6mm, highly flexing,  heavy and measuring 4'×8', how am i going to align the sheets side by side without gaps? Standard stick separation  and alignment method cannot be used for this.
2. How reliable the adhesion will be? Im living in Malaysia temperature & humidity are stable all around.

I cannot find anyone doing this in YouTube videos.  Is this an impossible feat?

Any advice and comments highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you use spray adhesive? It has excellent bonding quality, has similar qualities as contact cement and it let's you move your work a little after application.

Comment: Have you thought  out how this would wear and how hard it would be to replace if it wears or gets damaged? It might be better to apply the laminate to plywood or to thin cement board sheets and then use mechanical fasteners to attach that to the concrete wall. Of course this  would leave space for insects to harbor, but perhaps liberal application of boric acid before putting on the sheets would prevent  insect from using the space.

Comment: The reason you don't see this done very often is because it is difficult to do on a wall. I use old 1" metal blinds to keep the laminate from touching the countertop. When I get the position perfect I start pulling the blinds out and rolling to flatten the laminant. I have put full sheets on walls but it is tough with 2 people, it can be done but it is much more difficult on a wall and required 2 people to position the sheet.

Comment: You're not finding videos because it's not a good idea. A contact cement bond is not terribly reliable for vertical surfaces normally, and with your rough and porous surface you're reducing contact area 25-75%. I think you need to apply your laminate to something like BC plywood, then bond that to the wall with construction adhesive.

Comment: I also am concerned about adhesion. Typically laminate is applied to high-density particle board; a very hard, smooth, nonporous and dense surface. Additionally, the planer surface the counter top is nearly perfect flat.  The concrete wall cannot come close to meeting these specs. I would recommend an interior paneling.  If you are stuck on the laminate you will first need to apply a layer of something like 3/4" plywood, one side sanded.  Then sand and fill your joints. Then sand again.

Comment: After reading all your comments, i think the best way to do this is stick the hpl on 9mm plywood and then erect the board. But i worry the seam between the panels will show.